# Dynamic links firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to create dynamic link in firebase using flutter and when the link is clicked I want the link to be opened on **browser** and not on any android/ios app.

I already have a hosting domain in firebase but when I went to create a dynamic link in firebase console it's asking to **"Add the TXT records below to your DNS provider to verify you own firebaseapp.com"**. I don't know where to add this since I have hosted it only on https://xxx.firebaseapp.com.

```
{
     "source": "/patient/**",
     "dynamicLinks": true
}
```

Above values have been set already in firebase.json file.

Somebody please help in clarifying the TXT records issue and how to set the firebase domain itself to test the working of dynamic link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a `*.firebaseapp.com` subdomain as the origin of dynamic links. Instead, you have to use a `*.page.link` subdomain or a domain that you own. The verification must be put at the root of the domain (firebaseapp.com), which you don't have access to.